# creating interactive animation with libgdx

Tags: android, animation, libgdx, interactive, gesture-recognition

I am looking for a way to connect pan gesture with percentage of animation completion. Let me show you what I mean.

[image]

This image represents an animation that I want to execute, namely a moving Image actor or a sprite. The animation gets executed by **pan** gesture. Animation is 100% complete and at stage 6 when user slides for a 200px. If user slided only 100px, it would be 50% complete and at stage 3. If the user didn't execute pan gesture the animation stays at 0% and at stage 1.  I am looking for tips on how to start building such a model. I believe it is called interactive. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Have a Scroll View. Monitor how much it has scrolled. Set up your animation to animate in frames. animation current frame = Math.floor(scrollview.scrollX / scrollview.totalScrollX * animation.totalFrames)

Comment: good. the problem is that I cannot record frames in advance, because It is up to user to create it's own "blue rectangle"

Comment: You would have to explain in greater detail your scenario then. Even if the user is making his own content you should have control of the frames generated. I do not understand how my approach would need 'precomputed' values.

Comment: I was under impression that "Set up your animation to animate in frames" means supplying images generated in photoshop or similar tool and than run as a keyframe animation.

Comment: please be more specific..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a GestureDetector to handle the panning input. The `gestureListener.pan` method can update an animation position parameter.

```
private int screenPixelsToAnimationPositionRatio = 0.01f; //will need to tweak this and probably adjust it at runtime based on screen dimensions and resolution
private float animationPosition = 0; //from 0 to 1, fraction of animation complete

public void create () {

    //...

    GestureAdapter gestureAdapter = new GestureAdapter {
        @Override
        public boolean pan (float x, float y, float deltaX, float deltaY) {
            animationPosition += deltaX * screenPixelsToAnimationPositionRatio;
            animationPosition = MathUtils.clamp(animationPosition, 0, 1);
            return true;
        }
    };

    GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(gestureAdapter);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(gestureDetector); //or put the detector in an InputMultiplexer with your other input listeners.
}
```

Then you would create a method that can update your object's position and rotation based on the current value of `animationPosition`. You would need to figure out the equations that determine the movement you want. For example, something that looks sort of like what you illustrated above:

```
private void updateAnimation (){
    x = animationPosition * 30;
    float y = 0, rotation = 0;
    if (animationPosition >= 0.25f) { 
        float jumpPosition = Math.min(1, (animationPosition - 0.25f) / 0.5f);
        y = 30 * (1 - Interpolation.pow2In.apply(Math.abs(2 * jumpPosition - 1)));
        rotation = 180 * jumpPosition;
    }

    mySprite.setPosition(x, y);
    mySprite.setRotation(rotation);
}
```

Then call this update method somewhere in `render`.